# calling function returning user type from different schema in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to call a function inside a package which is returning a user defined type present in different schema.

The function and package declaration is like ---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PA_WEBHOOK
   AUTHID CURRENT_USER
IS
   TYPE gcur_table_data IS REF CURSOR;

   TYPE typ_tab_updated_ids IS TABLE OF orders.order_sid%TYPE;
FUNCTION fn_order_customer_get (p_str_order_id IN orders.order_id%TYPE) RETURN gcur_table_data;
END PA_WEBHOOK;
/
```

As it is clearly evident that function is returning a ref cursor as output for selected number of rows.

Now in order to achieve this, I have followed following steps--

1) creating a role --

```
CREATE ROLE ECOMMERCE_APP_ROLE;
```

2) providing privilege to role ---

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON  PA_WEBHOOK TO ECOMMERCE_APP_ROLE;
```

3) assigning role to user schema

```
GRANT ECOMMERCE_APP_ROLE TO ECOMM_APP;
```

4) creating synonym for the package in the other schema

Although I am able to call the function from different schema but I am getting null in the result set, but whenever I am executing the query mentioned in the function I can see the results.

Is it something because of type created inside the package, if yes can someone lead me the way to get the correct result set

Answer (score 1):

Your package is defined with `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` so when you call `PA_WEBHOOK.FN_ORDER_CUSTOMER_GET` from the source schema it works fine, but when you call it from the `ECOMM_APP` schema it uses `ECOMM_APP`'s privileges when running, not the defining schema's privs, and it uses the `ECOMM_APP` schema during name resolution instead of the defining schema when objects aren't fully qualified.

All this means that if `PA_WEBHOOK.FN_ORDER_CUSTOMER_GET` attempts to return a ref cursor to the `ORDERS` table (not qualified with the owners schema name) it will return a refcursor to different tables depending on which schema it's called from.  If your schema has an `ORDERS` table containing data you'll get data back, but if `ECOMM_APP` has an `ORDERS` table with no data it won't get any data back.  if `ECOMM_APP` doesn't have the referenced table the function is likely to throw an error.  It's possible that the function has an error handler that may be masking this situation.

Alternatively if `PA_WEBHOOK.FN_ORDER_CUSTOMER_GET` uses fully qualified table references, then perhaps the `ECOMM_APP` schema doesn't have select privs on them.  Again an error handler could be masking the lack of privs.

Without seeing the package body a lot of this is conjecture though.  You can read up on [Invoker's and Definer's Rights](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00809) in oracle's docs for more info.

Comment: The problem originally was with the function itself, as the max count for cursor was achieved in the system.

Comment: I already provided the mandatory privileges   i.e.                              execute on package,select/update/insert/delete on table , select on seq and execute on user defined type hence forth the privileges were not the issue. Issue was related to the configuration where the max cursor size mentioned was really low causing the problem in the function itself, get to know about this by removing the exception handling section from function.

Comment: Yes but are you using fully qualified table/object references e.g. `schema.table_name` or unqualified references e.g. `table_name`? In the later case when accessed by the same schema that owns the package then the function will find the referenced objects, but when accessed from another schema, it will only find the referenced objects if that schema has a local or global synonym pointing to the correct object, or the schema owns an object of the same name (and hopefully same type).  That's part of the point of the `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` statement.

Comment: for accessing the database objects I provided the grants to the other schema via a Role and then created private synonyms over there, this is now working fine and Yes I used fully qualified table/object references